# Confusion in implementing union using ctypes

Tags: python, c, unions

I am trying to write a code of union using ctypes, but it is not giving desired output...

Code given:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  union a
  { 
    int i;
    char ch[2];
  };
  union a key;
  key.i=512;
  printf("%d\n",key.i);
  printf("%d\n",key.ch[0]);
  printf("%d\n",key.ch[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
512
0
2
```

I tried it as:

```
#Demo of union at work
from ctypes import *
class a(Union):
    _fields_= [("i", c_int, 16),
               ("ch[2]",c_char)]
key=a()
key.i=512
print key.i
print key.ch[0]
print key.ch[1]

AttributeError: 'a' object has no attribute 'ch'
```

Didn't know why it is giving that error?

Any way to implement it?

Comment: Why did you choose to use a bitfield rather than, say, `c_short`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields of your union are declared incorrectly. You've declared an attribute named `"ch[2]"`.

To demonstrate this, have a look at this variant of your program:

```
#Demo of union at work
from ctypes import *
class a(Union):
    _fields_= [("i", c_int, 16),
               ("ch[2]",c_char)]
key=a()
key.i = 65
print getattr(key, "ch[2]")
```

**Output**

```
A
```

You probably meant to write code like this:

```
_fields_= [("i", c_int, 16),
           ("ch", c_byte*2)]
```

This declares `ch` to be an array of `c_byte`, with length 2.

Note that I use `c_byte` in place of `c_char` because you expect an integral type rather than a character.

So, here's the corrected program:

```
#Demo of union at work
from ctypes import *
class a(Union):
    _fields_= [("i", c_int, 16),
               ("ch",c_byte*2)]
key=a()
key.i=512
print key.i
print key.ch[0]
print key.ch[1]
```

**Output**

```
512
0
2
```

Comment: IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: Because OP wants to index it as if it were in C. Something I pointed out in my answer that would not work... BTW, who is downvoting these?